# how to change the piechart Data color

Tags: android, pie-chart

I have this piechart and I want to make the color of the data and the text the same , I have tried  pieDataSet.setValueTextColor but it doesnt work , do you guys how to change it .[image]

Comment: Are you using mpchart library?

Comment: Can you post your code here? And give detail information i.e. how to draw piechart?.

Comment: @aksacha yes Im using mpchart library

Comment: use `PieData` object and call `setValueTextColor`

Comment: try this way: `pieChart.setCenterTextColor(<yourcolor>);`